# Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, https

I am calling PayTM API from a window application using asp.net 3.5. 
This is my calling code

```
HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = null;
string postString = ReturnRequestUrl();
Uri DemorUri = new Uri(postString);
myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(DemorUri); 
myWebRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
myWebRequest.Method = "POST";
myWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
myWebRequest.Timeout = 180000;

StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(myWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream ReceiveStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode);
string response = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

But i am getting that error

```
    See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
************** Exception Text **************
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

This error in only coming on Window XP PC. 
I have already try

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

before calling that request.

Please help in that

Comment: "This error in only coming on Window XP PC. " - XP is *long beyond* end of life; if it can't support some scenario, at some point the answer has to be **stop using XP**... just sayin'

Comment: Yes i know but my some of client still using it that is my problem. I definitely need some solution for them.